# Can Sitecore be customized to auto save pages including the rich text editor?

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor, content-editor, richtext-editor

Trying to solve the issue where an editor is updating content and gets timed out.  When they log back in they lost changes.  I know you can increase that time out, but can you implement auto save?  Assuming they are using best practices and version the content before editing so they can get back changes if needed.  I found this, but it is out of date and download link doesn't work.
http://sitecoregadgets.blogspot.com/2011/11/rich-text-auto-save.html

Thanks!

Comment: Is this the exact error message that they see before being logged out? `The operation could not be completed. Your session may have been lost due to a timeout or a server failure. Please try again.` If it is please see this link: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/135940

Comment: I have managed to talk to Ivan on Sitecore Slack (author of the blog post) to get the package link updated but seems he doesn't have the package as of now and he said he will look into it. Meanwhile check if this link helps https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/135940 resolving the issue.

Comment: @HarshBaid beat you to it ;)

Comment: Fixed the link in the [blog article](https://sitecoregadgets.blogspot.com/2011/11/rich-text-auto-save.html). Keep in mind that article was written for Sitecore 6.4.1. You will likely need to make some adjustments to make it work with Sitecore 8+ versions.

Answer (score 1):

If the exact error message is the following then there is a support dll to help: `The operation could not be completed. Your session may have been lost due to a timeout or a server failure. Please try again.` Please see this link: [kb.sitecore.net/articles/135940](http://kb.sitecore.net/articles/135940). Basically, from what I understand, Sitecore is identifying your user as a bot because they haven't hit a frontend page before logging into the shell.